# disassembly of C array gives weird results

Tags: c, assembly, x86, x86-64, red-zone

```c
int square() {
    char test[50];
}
```

The above code produces

```
square():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
```

When i change the code a little to

```c
int square() {
    char test[150];
}
```

The assembly generated is

```
square():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 40
```

Which is still weird because I cannot understand why it does not allocate for previous creations. I'm running at -O0 so gcc doesn't optimize it out. Why is gcc creating code for wrong sized arrays?

```
int square() {
    char a[50];
    char b[50];
}
```

```
square():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 8
```

Similarly for x86

```
int square() {
    char a[500];
}
```

compiled with -m32 gives me:

```
square():
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 512
```

Where is this extra 12 bytes from? And why does -m32 have an sub instruction for char test[50] but x86_64 doesn't?

Comment: You are giving the compiler valid C code, but relatively useless functions.  The compiler is free to omit useless stuff in the generated code -- in fact, that's one of its primary objectives (though this does vary with implementations and command line options).  With a local array that isn't used, we should not have expectations. 
 One way to make a function useful is to pass parameters and compute return values.

Comment: Did you try to put some actual code that does something useful with the array(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is using the x86-64 System V ABI's 128-byte [Red Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) below the stack pointer for the variables, only reserving some extra stack space when that's not sufficient

For the last example, GCC `sub`s `512` to keep the stack (and the array) aligned.

The i386 System V ABI does not have a red zone so it has to reserve space for the whole array (neither does Windows x64, for that matter).

Comment: The only 32-bit code is the very last, where the stack allocation is the full array size.  The `sub rsp,8` is with two 50-byte arrays, each aligned by 16, with GCC probably wasting some extra space.  (They would both fit in the red-zone but GCC doesn't do that.).